# Print consecutive lines if the values of their first fields are matching

Tags: awk, sed, printing, field, matching

Using grep, sed or awk, I'd like to print consecutive lines, two or more, with a matching string in the n-th field. Here's an example:

Input file:

```
1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 5
2 3 4 1
4 1 3 2
```

Desired output:

```
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 5
```

The expression

```
awk '$1 == p1 {print p0} {p1 = $1; p0 = $0}' file
```

sort of works, but the last line with a matching pattern `$1` is not printed...

Comment: Kindly post sample of Input and output in code tags too.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$1==p1{print p0 $0; p0=""; next} {p0=$0 ORS; p1=$1}' file
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1h;1d;G;/^(\S+\s).*\n\1/{s/\n.*//;H;$ba;d};s/\n.*//;:a;x;/\n/p;x;h;d' file
```

Store the first line in the hold space for comparison and then delete it. For following lines, append the hold space to the current line and compare the first fields. If the first fields match, restore the current line, append it to the hold space and delete it (unless it is the last line). If first fields do not match, restore the current line, swap to the hold space and print it if it contains more than one line then swap back and replace the hold space with the current line and delete the current line. If there is a match and the current line is the last line an edge case is resolved by going to the hold space check using `$ba` and `:a...`.